# Error related to check_container_alive when publish a shiny app to shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, shinystore

I have designed a shiny app. When I tried to publish this app on `shinyapps.io`, I got the following error message.

> Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 958419875 error: Unhandled
> Exception: Timeout waiting for '_check_container_alive' after 0:00:30
> Execution halted

I have used `shinyapps.io` to publish other shiny apps, but this is the first time I encountered this error. The only thing I can think of for now is it is the first time I used an R package, [shinyStore](https://github.com/trestletech/shinyStore), not from CRAN, but from github. I am wondering if this may casue some issues.

Below is the R code. Please let me know how I can solve this issue.

```
### This script creates an example of using the shinyStore package

# Load packages
library(shiny)
library(shinyStore)

ui <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel("shinyStore Example"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel = sidebarPanel(
      initStore("store", "shinyStore-ex1"),
      textInput(inputId = "Text1", label = "Enter some texts")
    ),
    mainPanel = mainPanel(
      fluidRow(
        numericInput(inputId = "Number1", label = "Enter a number", value = NA),
        sliderInput(inputId = "Slider1", label = "Pick a number", min = 0, max = 100, value = 50),
        actionButton("save", "Save", icon("save")),
        actionButton("clear", "Clear", icon("stop"))
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    if (input$save <= 0){
      updateTextInput(session, inputId = "Text1", value = isolate(input$store)$Text1)
      updateNumericInput(session, inputId = "Number1", value = isolate(input$store)$Number1)
      updateSliderInput(session, inputId = "Slider1", value = isolate(input$store)$Slider1)
    }
    updateStore(session, name = "Text1", isolate(input$Text1))
    updateStore(session, name = "Number1", isolate(input$Number1))
    updateStore(session, name = "Slider1", isolate(input$Slider1))
  })
  
  observe({
    if (input$clear > 0){
      updateTextInput(session, inputId = "Text1", value = NA)
      updateNumericInput(session, inputId = "Number1", value = NA)
      updateSliderInput(session, inputId = "Slider1", value = 50)
      
      updateStore(session, name = "Text1", value = NA)
      updateStore(session, name = "Number1", value = NA)
      updateStore(session, name = "Slider1", value = 50)
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

#### Update

After several days, I tried to published the app on `shinyapps.io` again with the same code, and it worked. Now my guess is there were some connecting issues between me and  `shinyapps.io`, or `shinyapps.io` had some difficulties to install the `shinyStore` package. If someone can offer an explanation on this error message, I will accept that answer and reward the bounty.

Comment: [Here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/checking-current-status-of-shinyapps-io-and-deployment-work-with-r-version-3-5-1/14526/5) is a related thread. I guess the problem might be, that `shinyStore` isn't installed as it should.

Comment: @ismirsehregal Thanks for the related thread. I tried the code again today, and it works! Not sure that happened.